# How to implement doubly linked list in PHP?

Tags: php, linked-list

I got an interview question on Friday and I think I flunked it. The question was:

> Write a class that process a double linked list in PHP.

I understand the concept, and here's the code I gave:

```
class element {
 private $current;
 public function __construct($e) {
  $this->current = $e;
 }
 // method
 // etc..
}

class doublelist
{
  private $prev;
  private $next;
  private $current;
  private $list;
  public function add(element $e) {
   if($this->current == NULL) {
    $this->prev = $this->current;
   }
   $this->current = $e;
  }
}

$list = new doublelist();
$list->add(new element('a'));
$list->add(new element('b'));
```

This works initially, but if I add a second element I "lose" the first one, and I don't understand why.

Comment: `element` should have `prev` and `next` pointers, not `list`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to be keeping track of `$prev` and `$next` on the `element`s, not the list. If you want to make it transparent, you can wrap each `element` in a bean that has pointers to the next and previous ones, or just make `element` have those by definition.

The way you're doing it right now, the list will only know which one is the current `element`, and which one came before that. But what you should really be doing is figuring it out from the `element` (or bean) which one will be the next or previous.

**Edit**

Since this question has been getting the occasional view, I thought I'd add a little code to help explain this better.

```
class DoublyLinkedList {
    private $start = null;
    private $end = null;

    public function add(Element $element) {
        //if this is the first element we've added, we need to set the start
        //and end to this one element
        if($this->start === null) {
            $this->start = $element;
            $this->end = $element;
            return;
        }

        //there were elements already, so we need to point the end of our list
        //to this new element and make the new one the end
        $this->end->setNext($element);
        $element->setPrevious($this->end);
        $this->end = $element;
    }

    public function getStart() {
        return $this->start;
    }

    public function getEnd() {
        return $this->end;
    }
}

class Element {
    private $prev;
    private $next;
    private $data;

    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function setPrevious(Element $element) {
        $this->prev = $element;
    }

    public function setNext(Element $element) {
        $this->next = $element;
    }

    public function setData($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }
}
```

There are, of course, other methods you could add; and if anyone is interested in those I can add them as well.

Answer (score 6):

**Before coding anything, tell them**  it's already been done and is included in the PHP standard library.  http://php.net/manual/en/class.spldoublylinkedlist.php

---

Also, your add function shouldn't take an element.  It should just be `$list->add('a');`  You are exposing your implementation too much.

Comment: I understand that the question is more about skill, but I'd honestly tell that to an employer before coding a thing.  I feel opinionated enough about it to post it as an answer.